# building a simple ajax class in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a simple ajax class for a chrome extension. I get an undefined error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined` when I try to run the code. What seems to cause this issue?

```
function ajax(arguments, callback) {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.open(arguments.requestType, arguments.requestUrl + arguments.requestParameters, true);
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            requestedData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            callback(requestedData);
        }
    }
    this.xhr.send();
}

var ajaxRequest = new ajax({ 
    requestType: 'GET',
    requestUrl: 'http://ezswag.com/bots/terms.php',
    requestParameters: ' ',
    }, function(json) {
        //console.log(json);  => json {apple: "red", cheery: "red"}
        return json;
    });

    console.log(ajaxRequest);
```

**(Updated code, and working**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on how the function is being called.

When you call the `ajax` function as a constructor (note that convention says you should start constructor function names with a capital letter) `this` is the instance being created.

In the `readyState` function, `this` is the XMLHttpRequest object.

All your references to `this.xhr` inside the `readyState` function should be simply `this`

Comment: thank you. I updated the code with a callback. Is there a way to access the json data from the callback outside the function from the variable `ajaxRequest` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't use this.xhr inside the function. This does a reference to the current function and not what do you think.

Use a temp variable like this :

```
var self = this;

this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xhr.readyState === 4 && self.xhr.status === 200) {
        requestedData = JSON.parse(self.xhr.responseText);
        console.log(requestedData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onreadystatechange` implementation, `this` is not what you think it is.  You need to capture the scope of your `ajax` function and use that in your callbacks.

```
function ajax(parameter) {
    var that = this;
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.open(parameter.requestType, parameter.requestUrl + parameter.requestParameters, true);
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (that.xhr.readyState === 4 && that.xhr.status === 200) {
            requestedData = JSON.parse(that.xhr.responseText);
            console.log(requestedData);
        }
    }
    this.xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `this` instead of `that.xhr` inside the callback?